# ¿Cómo actuar ante sugerencias de ediciones rechazadas sin un motivo real?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, convenciones-sociales

Una de mis actividades favoritas en el sitio es corregir ortografía (sobre todo cuando son errores groseros), pero me he topado con ediciones en las que, a pesar de que fueron aceptadas por revisores, el dueño de la pregunta las rechaza sin una razón consistente.

Por ejemplo, [ésta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/449699/extraer-datos-de-un-while-con-una-variable), en la que hice esta [sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/269544), un revisor aprobó la edición y luego el dueño la rechazó, por lo que quedó con estatus de rechazada.

El motivo de la edición fue el siguiente:

> Comentario: Correcciones menores de ortografía y gramática

Y su feedback:

> Rechazar. Evitaria que los usuarios pidan información adicional que ya esta

Según mi parecer no tiene ningún sentido que rechazar una edición de ortografía sirva para que los usuarios no pidan información que ya cargó el dueño de la pregunta.

No creo que fuera malintencionado, sino más un desliz de usuario nuevo, pues viendo las estadísticas de edición fue la primera vez que una pregunta suya tuvo una sugerencia de edición y quizás no entendió de qué se trata.

Otro ejemplo, [ésta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454346/como-puedo-hacer-una-busqueda-de-datos-en-general-en-tiempo-real-de-todas-las-v) con éstas [ediciones sugeridas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/272554). Fue aprobada por un revisor, y rechazada por el dueño ya que "no considera que la edición mejore la calidad de la pregunta", cuando tengo entendido que sí. De hecho, se encuentra entre las sugerencias de motivo de edición.

Considero que es una situación que resulta frustrante tanto para quien edita como para el revisor, ya que es tiempo desperdiciado.

Comment: Si tu edición es rechazada, sea por el motivo que sea, no debería importante tanto. Después de todo es una sugerencia. Si alguien, tal y como dices tu, se ha equivocado, no creo que haya que recriminarle nada, es un error y ya. Con respecto a la rechazada por el dueño, yo apoyo esa moción, no se como solo una edición de ortografia mejore significativamente la pregunta. Por lo que nunca me han gustado esas ediciones. Prefiero que sean de diseño, estrucutura, o presentacion de datos. Si te fijas, hasta en este comentario, no existe ninguna sola tilde solo por ahorrarme el hacerlo.

Comment: @Excorpion Al editar algo, se muestra el siguiente texto ayuda: *"explica brevemente tus cambios (correcciones de gramática y ortografía, y mejoras de formato)."* Por lo que sí es una edición totalmente válida, y tiene su razón de ser: mejora la legibilidad.

Comment: Nunca dije que no es válido... dije que tal y como se menciona... es una sugerencia. No una obligación.

Comment: @Excorpion Si, ok, es una sugerencia solo por mi puntaje, pero si tengo 2000 puntos y edito una publicación con errores, debería quedar así. Revertirla para volver al mensaje original es prácticamente vandalismo... No es obligación escribir sin errores, pero corregirlos siempre es una mejoría. Y te escribí eso porque dijiste que no sabes cómo una edición de ortografía mejora significativa la pregunta. Si no la mejorara significativamente, SO no incentivaría a que se corrija la ortografía y gramática en las ediciones.

Comment: Aún así nunca dije que era inválido, eso son palabras mayores en ese caso. Si quieres editar y corregir esas cosas, es cosa tuya. No veo que debas hacer algo al respecto si una sugerencia es rechazada. Probablemente lo único que estás haciendo finalmente, es molestar al OP y por eso termina rechazándola. El está en su derecho de hacerlo de todos modos. Quizás necesites solo corregir algo, para que el OP mismo no termine rechazando algo válido.

Comment: @Excorpion No estoy de acuerdo en que el OP esté "en su derecho" de rechazar una edición de ortografía y gramática. Por supuesto, a menos que tenga un motivo válido para hacerlo. De hecho hacerlo repetidas veces es un acto malicioso y motivo como para contactar un moderador...

Comment: Si crees eso, te invito a hacer tu reclamo como lo ha hecho el OP.  Trata de ponerte en contacto con un moderador diamantado y expone tus excusas. Yo solo veo un error acá, y una rechazo, no veo lo malicioso de lo ocurrido. Si expandes algo más, te estás saliendo del tema de conversación.

Comment: @Excorpion Te invito a releer mi pregunta y mis comentarios para que veas que nunca hablé de mi situación en particular, sino que son simples ejemplos. Aclaré que mis rechazos seguramente fueron sin mala intención. Y en el comentario anterior fui claro al decir que si una persona repite este comportamiento a lo largo del tiempo es reportable, ergo (y el único ítem que te respondí), el OP no está en su derecho de rechazar estas sugerencias. Rechazar ediciones correctas múltiples veces podría considerarse vandalismo, y es el motivo de debate al que apunta la pregunta.

Comment: `el OP no está en su derecho de rechazar estas sugerencias` .. woah woah... como eso ?? Donde dice que no puede hacerlo ? Y en que momento SO se lo prohibe ¿?¿

Comment: Toda mejora suma y debe ser aprobada. De hecho, una coma puede cambiar el sentido de una oración. Por lo tanto, las correcciones ortográficas también son fundamentales, así como también lo es la gramatical, formato, entre otras. Por lo tanto, ese tipo de ediciones siempre las aprobaré.

Comment: Por el motivo de rechazo, apostaría que el autor vio el resumen de la edición, interpretó mal (por ejemplo que estabas eliminando texto, en vez de corrigiendo) y rechazó por eso. No le des tanta importancia a acciones puntuales de un usuario que no sabemos cuán familiarizado está con el uso del sitio: es probable que haya algo que no entienda.

Answer (score 13):

No encuentro ahora mismo la pregunta / respuesta, pero he comentado algo similar en otras preguntas similares: si alguien comete un error revisando sin malicia y no lo repite en el tiempo, lo mejor es dejarlo pasar y... tener paciencia con el resto de usuarios. Si eres activo en la comunidad (sobre todo respondiendo), en unos pocos meses alcanzarás la puntuación de reputación necesaria (2000 puntos) para que se te considere un usuario confiable y tus ediciones serán aplicadas inmediatamente, sin necesidad de aprobaciones/revisiones (también dejarán de puntuarte como sucede ahora).

Casi todos hemos pasado por alguna revisión frustrante en algún momento de nuestra estancia, no te desanimes. Por supuesto, si consideras que algún usuario está actuando incorrectamente repetidamente, intenta contactar con los moderadores diamantados: suelen tener herramientas y/o el conocimiento para resolver estas situaciones.

Comment: Hola, @Pablo. Las sugerencias de ediciones están acá [primera sugerencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/269544) y [segunda sugerencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/272554) rechazadas por el autor. Me gusta esta respuesta, es útil.